# How can the readability of files be listed recursively in Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, file-permissions

The `cacls` command in Windows XP and Vista can be used to deny read access to files to certain users. How can I find out which files in a directory tree are readable for a user after `cacls` has been run? A batch file solution is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the excellent [Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) command-line tool **[AccessChk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922)**.

I created an example folder **C:\test** and populated it with two files, **normal.txt** and **secure.txt**. The latter file was set to be permissioned only to my account whereas normal.txt has the default inherited permissions.

The command I then used was `accesschk -r -s Gareth C:\test` (display all the files in the folder test and below that the user Gareth has read-only access to). Here's the output:

```
Accesschk v5.01 - Reports effective permissions for securable objects
Copyright (C) 2006-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

RW C:\test\normal.txt
RW C:\test\secure.txt
```

I then ran it with another user: `accesschk -r -s AnotherUser C:\test` - here's the output:

```
Accesschk v5.01 - Reports effective permissions for securable objects
Copyright (C) 2006-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

RW C:\test\normal.txt
```

Hopefully that does the job!

Comment: only problem is that files as this command lists files which do have have read permissions, I get access denied errors. But I can grep for "Access denied" from the output and filter these out.